# how to check if input word has at least one uppercase?

Tags: python-3.x, uppercase

i have started doing things on python yesterday and i started a simple code login (email:password) so i wanna make the password needs to have at least one uppercase letter, i tried str.isupper, str.islower i've searched it for hours and nothing found more than isupper and islower, i have python3.
what i'm doing doesn't requires to register or something like that, you put a email and password with condition, the email needs to have at least 5 characters, a "@" and ".", the password needs to be at least 8 characters long and i wanna make the password needs to have at least one upper case.
Sorry for my bad English, my main is Spanish.
the code is a disaster i think but its my first time.

```
import sys
email = input("Email adress: ")
x = 8
while "." and "@" not in email:
    print("Invalid email adress")
    sys.exit()
if len(email) < 5:
    print("Invalid email adress")
    sys.exit()
else:
    print("Successfully added your email")

uppercase_count = 0
password = input("Password: ")
while len(password) < 8:
    print("Your password needs to be atleast 8 character long")
    break;
if password.():

    print("Successfully created your password")
else:
    print("Your password needs to have atleast one upper case")
```

Comment: Try to use **any()**

Comment: @DanielHao that was my first thought too, then I realized there's a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is:

```
if password.lower() != password:

    print("Successfully created your password")
else:
    print("Your password needs to have at least one upper case")
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if input word has at least one uppercase, try this :

```py
for i in password:
    if i.isupper():
        uppercase_count += 1
```

Comment: Thanks!! that helped me a lot <3